# When viewing superset embedded dashboards in a webserver on mobile devices, they won't work unless you access the supeset server URL first

Tags: mobile, dashboard, embedding, apache-superset, self-signed-certificate

We're using superset embedded dashboards on thru an apache2 webserver as part of a microsite of sorts.
When accessing the site thru a computer the dashboards embedded in the microsite are displayed perfectly fine. HOWEVER, when trying to access the site thru a mobile device we can't get the dashboards embedded to show up UNLESS we first acess the SuperSet server URL (not necesary to login to the server, just access the URL to load the server cert)

A few key details:

- We're working in a developement/homologation environment, not a production environment. Therefore we're using self-signed server certificates.
- the first time you access the webserver/SuperSet server URL, them having self-signed certs, you get a warning asking if you want to bail out or continue and install the cert anyways.
- we're working behind a corporate proxy, therefore we had to serve a bunch modules ourselves for embedding to work (this bit works fine).

Given that is mostly management and higher ups that will be using mobile devices to access the microsite with the embedded dashboards, we can't exactly ask them to first visit the SuperSet server URL and only then the microsite for the site to work correctly.